# NodeJs cat server empty JSON output issue

Tags: json, node.js

I a beginner following a nodejs tutorial.

From said tutorial, I generated the following code:

[Index.js]

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

var cats = require('./cats.js')(app);

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1/3000');
});
```

[Cat.js]

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = function(app){

_cats = [];

/*
    Create
 */
app.post('/cat', function(req, res){
    console.log('Testing: ' + req.body);
    res.json({info: 'Cat created successfully!'});
});

/*
    Read
 */
app.get('/cat', function(req, res){
    res.send(_cats);
});

.
.
.
.
```

When I start the node script, and post some json cat data as described in the tutorial, my web browser displays empty json brackets for each json input I made.

Can anyone tell me what I missed or I'm doing wrong? **Why do I get empty JSON brackets instead of my cat data printed out?**

I'm an utter newbie at NodeJS so I apologise if I have not described issues adequately.

UPDATE:

I'm using the Postman Chrome extension to POST json, `{'name':'sam','age':'1','type':'alley'}` to `http://localhost:3000/cat`.

The tutorial I'm following is on [PluralSight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/play-by-play-node-web-api-john-papa-sam-artioli/table-of-contents). I don't think it's accessible without an account but they do offer a couple of days free to get you started.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko: It's on PluralSight. I provided a link in the question but I don't think you can access it without signing up

Answer (score 1):

It's because the code you posted does not update the `_cats` array. The code for *post* handler should be:

```
app.post('/cat', function(req, res){
    console.log('Testing: ' + req.body);
    _cats.push(req.body); // This is the missing line
    res.json({info: 'Cat created successfully!'});
});
```

Here I assume that the body contains a single object and it is already parsed. If not, you can add required manipulations...

### Edit

It seems that the request body should be parsed. The *express* framework has an additional module, the **body-parser**, which is used for this purpose:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // this will parse json requests
```

For more information, see [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Shimon but I still get no response. req.body is entirely empty. I updated my question with some more details - if it would help

Comment: I also tried req.id, req.params.id, req.name, req.params.name etc but no result.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help - I appreciate it all. I added some more code from my index.js file which shows my attempt to use body-parser. Perhaps whatever I'm doing wrong would be more apparent

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this working sample:

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var cats = [];
var counter = 1;

app.post('/cat', function (req, res) {
    cats.push({id: counter, name: 'Jacklyn'});
    counter++;
    res.json({info:'cat created successfully'});
});

app.get('/cat', function(req, res) {
    res.json(cats);
});

app.listen(8888);
```

You need to send at least one `POST` request in order to have a cat in the array and after each new `POST` request the amount of cats will increase.